# Access variable space inside a function

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that contains several items. Inside a method, I want to make these available. This is what I am doing right now

```
def myFunc(stuff):        
    for foo, bar in stuff.items():
        locals()[foo] = bar
    testVar

foo = {'testVar': 0}
myFunc(foo)
```

However, I get (inside python 2.7)

```
NameError: global name 'testVar' is not defined
```

Perhaps doing this, I am not accessing the function scope but the local scope outside of it? How can I access the function scope?

**Emphasis**

This is an abstracted problem to show exactly what I want. In this scenario, ofc., accessing a dictionary would be the correct solution. But let's just assume that I have some reasons for doing this. The question is *not*:

- How can I access variables I stored in a dictionary? Should I use the dictionary?

It is

- **Given that I operate inside a function, and want to access the variables directly in that function, how do I have to unzip the dictionary?**

Comment: Your indenting is severely off.

Comment: Fixed the indenting - had some issues with the WYSIWYG editor (that is, I can't count to four).

Comment: No, you cannot add new local names to a function; `locals()` is read-only. The scope of `testVar` is determined at parse time, not at runtime.

Comment: Just use a regular dictionary, don't try to create new names on the fly.

Comment: This is a very abstracted problem, the long story is long. I want these to be variables and not a dictionary. I have to temporarily zip them in the dictionary for saving purposes, but I want to have them "ready", not inside some dictionary.

Comment: Looks like you wanted to use a `**kwargs` call signature instead: `def myFunc(testVar): ...` and `myFunc(**foo)`.

Comment: Martijn, you are wrong in that `locals()` is read only, at least for 2.7.

Comment: @FooBar: No, you misunderstand the nature of the dictionary. You can alter it, but **no locals are set** from it. It is a one-way street only. See the other post I dupe-closed this question of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54440/discussion-between-foobar-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved now after some chatting, but just for the sake of history:

- There is no nice way of doing so.
- While `locals()` seem to be working outside of function space in older Python, there is nothing similar inside the function scope.

Quite a drawback I would say, personally, but whatever.